# Python3 Not Printing Expected Values For Bytes

Tags: python-3.x

Python version 3.8.10

I don't understand what's going on here.  I input the following bytestring and it gives a different value on print.

```
packet = b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x35\x03\x19\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00'

print(packet) #result b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x085\x03\x19\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00'
```

Same thing when using bytearray.

```
packet = bytearray()
packet.append(2)
...
packet.append(0)

print(packet) #result bytearray(b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x085\x03\x19\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00')
```

I know Python handles strings in a specific encoding, but I think that shouldn't matter given the way I input the bytes (not a string). I considered the print function sees the \x3 and evaluates as ASCII, but that makes no sense for this case (for my understanding anyway).

I really just want to understand what's going on.  I searched other posts (Google too) and was not able to find a similar situation.  Most other posts were from incorrectly handling encode() and decode() for their ASCII values, or issues when packing bits/bytes, which is obviously not the same situation here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but that makes no sense for this case" Can you clarify why? Note that ``0x35 == ord(b'5')`` and ``b'\x35' == b'5'``.

Comment: I think OP just wants a way to make it so it prints exclusively bytes instead of automatically decoding the bytes to ascii... which I agree would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same string/bytes/data anyway. What's the difference here?

```
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08\x35\x03\x19\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00'
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x08   5\x03\x19\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00'
```

Evidently, `b'\x35' == b'5'`.

Indeed, `0x35` is the ASCII code for the character `'5'`:

```
>>> b'\x35'
b'5'
```